# Save not working using mssql

Tags: sql-server, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying the following code but not working in mssql and not producing any error message in CakePHP, using version 2.6:

```
$product_id = $this->request->data['products']['product_id'];
$this->request->data['ProductTbl']['id'] = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$this->request->data['ProductTbl']['retailerId'] = $this->request->data['products']['retailer_id'];
$this->request->data['ProductTbl']['productCode'] = $product_id;
$this->request->data['ProductTbl']['productType'] = $this->request->data['products']['product_type'];
//$this->request->data['ProductTbl']['mmGroupId'] = $this->request->data['products']['merchandise_id'];
$this->request->data['ProductTbl']['name'] = $this->request->data['products']['product_name'];
$this->request->data['ProductTbl']['description'] = $this->request->data['products']['product_desp'];
$this->request->data['ProductTbl']['isLayawayable'] = $this->request->data['products']['product_layway'];
$this->request->data['ProductTbl']['isTaxExemptible'] = $this->request->data['products']['product_tax'];
$this->request->data['ProductTbl']['productURL'] = $this->request->data['products']['product_url'];
$this->request->data['ProductTbl']['status'] = 2;           
$this->request->data['ProductTbl']['lastModified'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');           
$this->request->data['ProductTbl']['isDeleted'] = 0;    
if(!empty($this->request->data['pjosn'])){
    $pjson_arr = $this->request->data['pjosn']; 
    $this->request->data['ProductTbl']['propertiesJson'] = json_encode($pjson_arr);
}
$this->ProductTbl->save($this->request->data['ProductTbl'],false);
$last_id = $this->ProductTbl->getLastInsertID();
```

Thanks.

Comment: "not working" is not descriptive. What version of CakePHP is that, and what is _actually_ happening? What sql queries are issued? You aren't checking the return value of `$this->ProductTbl->save` at all at the moment.

Comment: it's not inserted into the database in cakephp 2.6 and i getting the return value as false.

Comment: Check for validation errors (`debug($this->ProductTbl);`) and/or step through the save method to see _why_ it returns false. "Code doesn't work. Why?" is not a good question to ask when showing no effort to find out why. Note that calling `getLastInsertID` _at all_ suggests not understanding how CakePHP works.

Comment: It's not a very good idea to set `strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))` as id. What if two people subit a form simultaneously? A timestamp is not a unique value and an id field should always be unique.

Comment: In cakephp will work getLastInsertId method.if i am also debug this method but did not produce any errors.

Comment: If i am hard code the Id but it doesn't insert into the database

Answer (score 0):

why are u using second argument 'false' in save function ???

i thinks possible issue should be second argument. I am using cakePHP 2.7.5 and  according to me your save query will be ::

```
$res = $this->ProductTbl->save($this->request->data);
if($res){
// do whatever you wants 
}
```

Or the second issue may be  in following code :

```
if(!empty($this->request->data['pjosn'])){

$pjson_arr = $this->request->data['pjosn'];

$this->request->data['ProductTbl'['propertiesJson']=json_encode($pjson_arr);

 }
```

in json_encode your data will be in joson format ( like : {"key1":value1,"key2":value2,"key3":value3,"key4":value4,"key5":value5} ) which will not be accepted by cakePHP insert query.